# Set min date in materializecss" date picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, materialize

Does someone know how to set min date for "materializecss" date picker?
Official web site doesn't content information about it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

datepicker in [Material Design](http://materializecss.com/) uses [pickadate.js](http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/date/) internally. And documentation for this is avaialble [here](http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/date/). So this should work:

```
$('.datepicker').pickadate({
  min: new Date(2015,3,20),
  max: new Date(2015,7,14)
});
```

As mentioned [here](http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/date/#limits).

Here is an working example: https://jsfiddle.net/ashishanexpert/oxdbyk7t/

Comment: Can I set this on the fly?That is can I set min date on one picker while I click other one?

Comment: Even through pickadate is used in materialize, I can't get this implementation to work. And yes @sachithkn, if it worked in the first place you could indeed use one date picker to set the min/max of a second date picker. That's exactly what I'm trying to do actually.

Comment: @NativeCoder I dont understand why did this not work for you because I have put a working demo in this solution too...

Comment: It works for pickadate, but not for materialize. I actually found a way to do it on materialize's github. It's similar, but quite different at the same time.

Comment: Just want to mention that `new Date(2020,0,13)` will be the correct notation for january the 13th. Because `0` is the **index** of january which could be counter intiutive to somebody. I prefer `new Date('2020-01-01')` notation which is more intiutive IMHO. https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: Outdatet - see my answer which is up to date for version 1 https://stackoverflow.com/a/60159108/3931192

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
    onOpen: function () {
        var instance = M.Datepicker.getInstance($('.datepicker'));
        instance.options.minDate = new Date(YOUR_DATE);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

For Materialize version 1 things have changed:

```css
.datepicker::placeholder {
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="datepicker" placeholder="click and pick: only today available per setting">

<script>
jQuery('.datepicker').datepicker({ // intitiate datepicker for each element with class name "datepicker"
  minDate  : new Date(), // set minimum date to "today"
  maxDate  : new Date(), // set maximum date to "today"
  autoClose: true        // enable date picking on a very small window
})
</script>
```

### References

- [Materialize Date Picker](https://materializecss.com/pickers.html)
- [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference)